# How to reverse this dpkg-divert command?

Tags: 15.04, dpkg, upstart, systemd

I need to reverse what these lines did:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

I did this to switch from systemd to upstart so I could finish installing a broken package and remove it.

Currently my system is not loading any UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, just didn't know what dpkg-divert was doing. It made a backup (`initctl.distrib`) so `sudo rm /sbin/initctl && sudo mv /sbin/initctl.distrib /sbin/initctl` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today on my 16.04 on VMWare Workstation 12 on Windows 10. After entering initial login details, Ubuntu was not going any further. Had to get into Advanced Options mode --> Drop root shell (paraphrased) to remove and replace `/sbin/initctl` as shown by `Enigma` above, but the Advanced Options mode runs a read-only filesystem. Had to drop into my sudo user to be able to override the read-only, filesystem mode.